# Compiling many different projects with g++ and running

Tags: c++, batch-file, g++

I'll preface this by saying that I have searched around the internet but can't find something that has the capability of doing what I want.

I have a large amount of C++/C/C# projects from my earlier days of programming (something like 400+) and I recently decided to dig them out.

Folder structure:

```
-Projects
    -Project_1
        main.cpp
        //random other cpp/c/h files
     -Project_2
        main.cpp
        ....
```

Some of the projects were abandoned or are duplicates that have been updated (my old computers file system was a mess) I'd like to be able to do something similar to this pseudo-code via batch or possibly c++.

```
For each folder in projects
    get all cpp/h files and copy them to new folder inside a new directory called Processed
    attempt g++ compile (i'm going to ignore C# for now)

    if g++ was successful:
        run the executable/save output to output.txt

    if g++ not successful:
        output g++ failure message to errors.txt
```

Does anyone know how I would achieve this? I have attempted to find answers to my questions but so far I've only been able to find how to list all folders in a directory as such:

```
for /d %%D in (*) do echo %%~fD


REM run executable and output to file
main.exe > output.txt
```

Comment: Have you considered writing your script in a less awful language? (I personally use Python for this kind of thing, but tastes differ.)

Comment: Yeah I actually thought about using python after I posted this and I'm currently trying to figure out a small script that will do what I want, if you already have something similar I'd love to take a look.

Comment: Python is a good idea IMHO because you might be able to reuse your script on other OS. You can take a look at the [os Python package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). It lets you deal with processes and things like that. Be careful though not all functions run on all OS. Even if your script is not portable, at least it will be easier to read and maintain since Python has a more "modern" look and feel.